# Security Cams - Power through PoE Keystone Jack?

Tags: ethernet, home-networking, power-over-ethernet

I wired up some PoE security cameras at my home, using solid core CAT6 cable. I can do a direct connection from camera to the surveillance box, but to make it clean and allow for flexibility, would like to mount the camera wires to punchdown keystone jacks in the wall then use CAT6 patch cables to connect the surveillance box to the wall jack.

Not sure if this is accepted practice with PoE devices, or if it's best to just do the direct run. This is all CAT6 wiring with no run longer than 75 ft.

I did test using a coupler and video and audio quality was fine.

So instead of:

`Camera --> CAT6 Cable --> Surveillance Box`

do:

`Camera --> CAT6 Cable --> Keystone Wall Jack --> CAT6 patch cable --> Surveillance Box`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using keystone jacks is fine.  I have 16 cameras set up similarly with no issues.

In my case:
Camera -> cat6 cable -> wall jack -> inter-wall cable run -> patch panel -> patch cable -> PoE switch -> surveillance box

Just be careful when punching things down or you may get a jack that will transmit data, but won't carry PoE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is acceptable and recommended to terminate with a patch cord rather than the solid cable.

Until recently, it was not TIA compliant to directly attach plugs to horizontal cable (cable that is designed for in-wall installation). Now it is compliant to do so, and it is known as MPTL (modular plug terminated link) or direct attachment.

`Camera --> CAT6 Cable --> Surveillance Box` with suitable plugs to attach to the solid-copper horizontal cable would be the new MPTL (or direct attachment) method.

Including a patch cord and an outlet is the traditionally compliant way to do it and is still acceptable.

[TIA Recognizes MPTL Connections and You Should Too](https://www.flukenetworks.com/blog/cabling-chronicles/tia-recognizes-mptl-connections-and-you-should-too)